# Alternative to friendship?

Tags: c++, encapsulation, friend, access-control

Is there any alternative to friendship in the following scenario?

I have a `Window` class which represents an UI window. Also, a `WindowManager` class, implemented as a singleton, manages all window objects in my application (renders the UI, dispatches events, etc.)

The `WindowManager` will have a public interface consisting of only its singleton instancing method and functions to render the UI and to dispatch an UI event.

I would also like `Window` objects to register with the `WindowManager` during construction and to de-register during destruction. The `WindowManager::register` and `WindowManager::deregister` methods will be either private or protected, because I do not want clients (other than `Window` objects) to be able use this interface.

Is there a method to avoid friendship between `Window` and `WindowManager` in this case? Perhaps a totally different way to achieve similar results?

Comment: Is there some reason that you don't want Window and WindowManager to be friends?  Did they both used to date the same girl, so now it's too awkward or what?

Comment: :)) nope, but as a beginning C++ programmer perhaps I'm trying too hard to avoid coupling, even when I shouldn't.

Comment: It's good to stop and ask yourself questions like "Is there really an advantage to coupling these two things together?" or "Can I build these two parts in a way where there are less dependencies between them without sacrificing clarity or performance?"  But if there is going to be a dependency, it's best that that dependency be done in the clearest, cleanest, and most straight-forward way.  It's much better to look at a class and immediately know what other classes its connected to than to look at it and have to try to work out complex connections by looking at little subtle things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but friendship is the best solution, since it's designed for this scenario.

Another way is to make `Window` a member of `WindowManager` (note, this requires the new C++11 accessibility rules).  Or have it derive from a member of `WindowManager`.  Or have it derive from `WindowManager` itself.

You can also put a private type inside `Window`, make a key type nested in `Window` which can only be constructed from that private type, and require passing an instance of that key type to `WindowManager`.  This should work in pre-C++11 compilers.

Of course, any approach can be bypassed using enough casting.

Comment: I am somehow not comfortable with `Window` derive from `WindowManager` because they do not have an "is-a" relationship.

Comment: @dandrestor: I told you friendship is better.  These other methods will work, although they aren't ideal.

Comment: @dandrestor: This is a custom made scenario for friendship. That is the best design, Any other design will result in a cluttered design.

Comment: Thanks everybody. It looks like I will stick to friendship.

Comment: @Als it really depends on the problem. If this is a homework/tutorial project then friendship is a shortest and easiest way. In case dandrestor wants to model some "real" GUI toolkit functionality - there is a risk that friendship can choke on one limitation - it is not a subject to inheritance. IHMO GUI toolkits are projects where polymorphism is highly used.

Comment: @Marcin: Given the problem statement `Friends` is the most appropriate solution,I do not suggest Friendship because it the easiest way but because it is the most appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Friend`ship seems appropriate here.You want to indicate an **Intentional strong coupling** between the two classes, which is aptly indicated through friends.

More specifically, one class needs access to another classes's internals and you don't want to grant access to everyone by using the public access specifier.

The rule of thumb: is public is too weak and private is too strong, you need some form of selected access: either protected or friend.

Using `Friend`ship is the Best solution here.

Answer (score 2):

Use nested classes.

```
WindowManager {
  private:
    static void construct();
    static void destruct();
  public:
    class InternalWindow { // can access WindowManager's private members (no scoping needed)
      InternalWindow() { construct(); }
      ~InternalWindow() { desstruct(); }
    };
};

typedef WindowManager::InternalWindow Window; // to make scoping easier
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution (not necessary better :]) is to put the window registration to `a separate component` - let's say the WindowRegister. WindowRegister can have a public interface for registration and can also be a private member of a WindowManager.

The `problem with friendship is that it is not inherited` (a friend of my grandpa is not necessary my friend) - and there is a big chance that either Window or WindowManger will be polymorphic.

Regards

Comment: Indeed, I plan to make `Window` polymorphic. I will look into your `WindowRegister` idea, thanks!

Comment: How about 'my friend's nephew is my friend as well'? If I make `Window` a friend of `WindowManager`, will all classes that inherit from `Window` be able to register themselves as well?

Comment: Depends on how you structure things.  They won't be able to call register from their own methods, but they can still use the methods of their superclass.  So, if, for instance, there's a protected registerMyself method Window, then they can still call that.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thanks, Keith.

Answer (score 1):

There are several other options.  For example:

- You could use pointer math, assembly code, and knowledge about the layout of the classes in memory to call private methods at runtime.  This, however, is not very portable.
- You could make the method public, but require that it take a parameter cryptographically signed by a private key which lives in the Window class, thus preventing other classes from being able to actually call the method and have it do anything.
- You could make the method protected and make one inherit from the other.
- You could make a common superclass which they both inherit from and use protected methods from it to communicate between them.
- You could use the little used "enemy" keyword to allow them to run each other's private methods, but only when they have blackmail material which incriminates the other class.  (Okay, that's not a real language feature, but it should be.)

Or you could just make them friends.  That's much easier and saner than any of the other options and why friends exist.

Comment: (Note: the above comment was made in response to someone telling me that there was no enemy keyword in C++.  Said person, who shall remain nameless, has since removed his/her comment.)